# Filling the same data for many rows with minor addition

Tags: excel

I have some data as follows:

```
         Organization Name       Mail        Role1  Role 2 Role3 
         XYZ          Kumar      kumar@.com  A      B      C
```

which I need separate in rows for each role as shown, so my requirement is:

```
       Organization  Name       Mail        Roles
       XYZ           Kumar      kumar@.com  A
       XYZ           Kumar      kumar@.com  B
       XYZ           Kumar      kumar@.com  C
```

Is there any method to make it done?

Comment: What have you tried and what direction are you wanting to go? Do you want a formula or VBA? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have many rows of organizations and name. Assuming `Oganization` is in A1, insert a new ColumnD and populate it to suit with:

```
  =A1&"|"&B1&"|"&C1
```

To the populated range of ColumnsD:G apply the unpivot process as described in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20543651/1505120). Having created the Table insert new ColumsB:C, delete ColumnD and apply Text To Columns to ColumnA, with `|` as the delimiter. Adjust the labels to suit.